# Quickly implement a sortable table of objects in Django

Tags: python, django

Hey all. I have a question on how to implement the following with Django. I'd like to display a tabular view of my objects with each column corresponding to a particular model field. I'd like to be able to have the user sort the columns or search through all of them. Basically just like the admin, but client facing and read-only. It's simple, but I was wondering if there was a way I could implement this without having to write all that logic from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex Gaynor's [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter) may be what you want.

Comment: It wasn't, but it will be useful for adding to it. I'm using http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/308/ for the sortable headers, and I will use Alex's app to allow the user to further filter the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you wanted to work with it, Yahoo YUI's DataTable control is pretty easy to get working with a JSON data source. See http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/